# Pie Chart from Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-express

I'm trying to create a `plotly.express` pie chart from data that's in a data table.
The data originates from a Mongo query, and these queries populate the data table.
Using what I have here, the data table works as expected, but I have no pie chart.
Can anyone tell me how to correctly load this data frame for the pie chart?

`animal_id` and `breed` are the names of two columns in the data frame/data table.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
dash_table.DataTable(
    id='datatable-id',
    columns=[
        {"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": False, "selectable": True} for i in df.columns
    ],
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    editable=False,
    filter_action="native",
    sort_action="native",
    sort_mode="multi",
    column_selectable=False,
    row_selectable="single",
    row_deletable=False,
    selected_rows=[],
    page_action="native",
    page_current=0,
    page_size=10
),

html.Div(
    dcc.Graph(
        id="pie-chart"
    )
)
```

---

```
@app.callback(
    Output("pie-chart", "figure"),
    [Input("datatable-id", "data")]
)
def generate_chart(data):
    dfc = pd.DataFrame(list(data))

    fig = px.pie(dfc, values='animal_id', names='breed')

    return fig
```

---

The source data is loaded into a pandas data frame by querying a MongoDB database

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(db.collection.find({}))
```

and this is a sample of one of the db records:

```
> db.collection.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fccfabbfb3f7580efe722cd"),
    "" : 1,
    "age_upon_outcome" : "3 years",
    "animal_id" : "A746874",
    "animal_type" : "Cat",
    "breed" : "Domestic Shorthair Mix",
    "color" : "Black/White",
    "date_of_birth" : "2014-04-10",
    "datetime" : "2017-04-11 09:00:00",
    "monthyear" : "2017-04-11T09:00:00",
    "name" : "",
    "outcome_subtype" : "SCRP",
    "outcome_type" : "Transfer",
    "sex_upon_outcome" : "Neutered Male",
    "location_lat" : 30.5066578739455,
    "location_long" : -97.3408780722188,
    "age_upon_outcome_in_weeks" : 156.767857142857
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and congratulations on you first question. A little pice of advice: If you want people o troubleshoot your code, a good idea is to post a sample of your data. The risk, otherwise, is that people will move on to the next question.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes thanks.  I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  Callback as such:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("pie", "figure"),
    [Input("datatable-id", "data")]
)
def generate_chart(data):
    dff = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

    fig = px.pie(
        dff,
        names='breed',
    )

    return fig
```

I guess `values` is implied is the call to `px.pie()`